# Как почистить All_scheduler_job_log?

Tags: sql, oracle

Есть некоторое количество JOBs, которые записываются в представление `all_scheduler_job_log`. Представление системное и у меня есть права только на чтение. Когда-нибудь придется почистить представление логов.

Как это сделать с правами доступа только на чтение?

Answer (score 3):

Oracle автоматически чистит логи scheduler'а раз в день. По умолчанию всё, что старше 30 дней. Если не устраивает, можно изменить:

`exec dbms_scheduler.set_scheduler_attribute('log_history','21');`

Если у Вас не хватет прав, обратитесь к администратору БД.